# facing error while enroll and register in hyperledger fabric using node SDK

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I need help guys. I am developing custom HLF network with 2Orgs.The Fabric network is perfectly working with cli ,when i want to connect with node sdk ,then error come. i succesfully enrolled the admin but failed to register the user and faces error  while enrolling and regitering the user1.[you can see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BZCF.png) and [ca container logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36HYq.png).Files are mentioned below
the  Thanks in advance

**enrollAdmin.js file**

```
'use strict';

const FabricCAServices = require('fabric-ca-client');
const { FileSystemWallet, X509WalletMixin } = require('fabric-network');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const ccpPath = path.resolve(__dirname , '..'  , 'connectionprofileOrg1.json');
const ccpJSON = fs.readFileSync(ccpPath, 'utf8');
const ccp = JSON.parse(ccpJSON);

 async function main() {
   try {

    // Create a new CA client for interacting with the CA.
    const caInfo = ccp.certificateAuthorities['ca.org1.example.com'];
    const caTLSCACerts = caInfo.tlsCACerts.pem;
    const ca = new FabricCAServices(caInfo.url, { trustedRoots: caTLSCACerts, verify: false }, caInfo.caName);

    // Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities.
    const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
    const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath);
    console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);

    // Check to see if we've already enrolled the admin user.
    const adminExists = await wallet.exists('admin');
    if (adminExists) {
        console.log('An identity for the admin user "admin" already exists in the wallet');
        return;
    }

    // Enroll the admin user, and import the new identity into the wallet.
    const enrollment = await ca.enroll({ enrollmentID: 'admin', enrollmentSecret: 'adminpw' });
    const identity = X509WalletMixin.createIdentity('Org1MSP', enrollment.certificate, enrollment.key.toBytes());
    await wallet.import('admin', identity);
    console.log('Successfully enrolled admin user "admin" and imported it into the wallet');

} catch (error) {
    console.error(`Failed to enroll admin user "admin": ${error}`);
    process.exit(1);
}
}

 main();
```

**register.js file**

```
'use strict';

const { FileSystemWallet, Gateway, X509WalletMixin } = require('fabric-network');
const path = require('path');

const ccpPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'connectionprofileOrg1.json');

async function main() {
    try {

    // Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities.
    const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
    const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletPath);
    console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);

    // Check to see if we've already enrolled the user.
    const userExists = await wallet.exists('user1');
    if (userExists) {
        console.log('An identity for the user "user1" already exists in the wallet');
        return;
    }

    // Check to see if we've already enrolled the admin user.
    const adminExists = await wallet.exists('admin');
    if (!adminExists) {
        console.log('An identity for the admin user "admin" does not exist in the wallet');
        console.log('Run the enrollAdmin.js application before retrying');
        return;
    }

    // Create a new gateway for connecting to our peer node.
    const gateway = new Gateway();
    await gateway.connect(ccpPath, { wallet, identity: 'admin', discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true } });

    // Get the CA client object from the gateway for interacting with the CA.
    const ca = gateway.getClient().getCertificateAuthority();
    const adminIdentity = gateway.getCurrentIdentity();

    // Register the user, enroll the user, and import the new identity into the wallet.
    const secret = await ca.register({ affiliation: 'org1.department1', enrollmentID: 'user1', role: 'client' }, adminIdentity);
    const enrollment = await ca.enroll({ enrollmentID: 'user1', enrollmentSecret: secret });
    const userIdentity = X509WalletMixin.createIdentity('Org1MSP', enrollment.certificate, enrollment.key.toBytes());
    await wallet.import('user1', userIdentity);
    console.log('Successfully registered and enrolled admin user "user1" and imported it into the wallet');

} catch (error) {
    console.error(`Failed to register user "user1": ${error}`);
    process.exit(1);
}
}

main();
```

**connectionprofileOrg1.json**

```
{
    "name": "byfn",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "organization": "Org1",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300"
                }
            }
    }
},
"organizations": {
    "Org1": {
        "mspid": "Org1MSP",
        "peers": [
            "peer0.org1.example.com"
        ],
        "certificateAuthorities": [
            "ca.org1.example.com"
        ]
    }
},
"peers": {
    "peer0.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "grpcs://localhost:7051",
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "path": "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/tlsca/tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem"

        },
        "grpcOptions": {
            "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.example.com",
            "hostnameOverride": "peer0.org1.example.com"
        }
    }

},
"certificateAuthorities": {
    "ca.org1.example.com": {
        "url": "https://localhost:7054",
        "caName": "ca.example.com",
        "tlsCACerts": {
            "path": "crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem"          
          },
        "httpOptions": {
            "verify": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure connectionprofileOrg1.json file exists and it is in correct directory as you defined in enrollAdmin.js

Comment: yeah , connection profile path is correct.if not then how enrollAdmin.js can run successfully run.

Comment: Try to register with another identity. Error saying it all user1 is already registered.

Comment: thank you bro it works whit user2 .but also work when i restart my network means,generated new config transactions and created new order and peer organizations  again then put user1 in register.js then it works smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your error msg say it the user1 is already registered with ca server so you have to restart the network or you have to remove that identity from ca server. I suggest you restart the network and remove all from the wallet folder then it will work. Or try it with a different identity like user

Comment: thank you bro it works whit user2 .but also work when i restart my network means,generated new config transactions and created new order and peer organizations again then put user1 in register.js then it works smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you already have "user1" registered. Try to delete the local file generated from your enrollment or you should set your user registration dynamically

Comment: it worked when i change the user1 to user2 ,it successfully registered